# Recover Desktop Configuration from Unbootable Windows Drive

Tags: windows, bsod

I am currently browsing a unbootable windows drive via Ubuntu Live and was wondering if there was any way to recover my desktop (icons & files) so that when I get the new drive and reinstall everything I can get it as back to normal as possible

Note: I am a creature of habit

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C:\Documents and Settings\" this is the main directory that stores people's "My Documents", desktop icons, start menu program shortcuts, etc. If it is just a single user you are concerned about just copy the "All Users" folder and the "UserName" folder.

When you get your new XP up and running, copy these folders into their respective spots.

Comment: though I would avoid copying the ntuser.dat file(located at c:\documents and settings\username\ntuser.dat), copying the old registry is a source of endless pain.